# Does it make sense to talk about different group operations when every group is isomorphic to another one under composition?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $(G,+)$, or to simplify, just $G$, is a group. Then we can construct a bijective function $h$ defined as

$$h(b)=\{(a,c)\mid a+b=c\}$$

clearly, $h(a)$ is a function for all $a\in G$ with domain $G$ and image $G$. Now, $(\text{Im }h,\circ)$ is a group under composition that is indeed isomorphic to $G$, where $h$ is their isomorphism. Then why do we bother on selecting different operators when in reality we are analyzing the group formed by $\text{Im }h$ under function composition?

Comment: The image of $h$ as given is not $G$ but some subset of $G\times G$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, indeed, the claim is that $h: G \to S(G)$ is a monomorphism. This is the standard construction to prove Cayley's Theorem.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I didn't say that the image of $h$ is $G$, I said the image of $h(a)$ is.

Comment: @MeesdeVries What is $S(G)$?

Comment: @Garmekain, the symmetric group on the set $G$, i.e. the group of all bijections $G \to G$ under the composition operation.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what your question is, but the closest I can get is "Why do we use operations other than composition when every group is isomorphic to a group whose operation is composition?" Is that your question?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes, if every group is isomorphic to one under composition, why bother using other operations? Is it just because it is more convenient to write $a+b$ instead of $f_b(f_a(e))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If every group is isomorphic to one under composition, why bother using other operations?

The real answer is probably, *why not*?

We could indeed define a group to be a subset of bijections of a set which is contains the identity and is closed under composition and taking the inverse. Group theory-wise, we do not really lose anything. However, we encounter lots of operations in mathematics which *are not* composition, yet turn out to be groups. For example, the addition on the integers $\mathbb Z$ makes $(\mathbb Z, +)$ a groups (and a very important one). We could say that whenever we want to talk about $(\mathbb Z, +)$ as a group we should instead be talking about the group of integral translations on $\mathbb Z$, but what does that gain us? The notation is at best no simpler, and it becomes more complex when the group structure interacts with different things. For example, the underlying additive group of a ring is an abelian group, but if you want to talk about that group as consisting of bijections, then talking about multiplication becomes awkward. (In fact, multiplication is an operation which is much more like function composition anyway....)

If your answer to "why not?" is because it's more complicated to talk about all possible operations rather than just composition: Cayley's theorem (which you've essentially stated in your post) shows that it's not. Composition already contains all possibly complexity that any other group operation could contain, precisely because any group operation can very simply be transformed into composition.

All of this said, though: if you are just starting with group theory it is not a bad idea to view most groups as groups of bijections. This is a view that is in a sense much more mature than abstractly viewing groups as "sets with operations", since in practice interesting groups arise as automorphism groups of other (structured) objects.